# How to prevent selection of all pending files after checkin in team foundation server

Tags: visual-studio-2008, user-interface, tfs

When I check-in/Undo Check in, all the remaining files in "Pending Changes" get automatically checked (i.e check-boxes are selected for all the remaining files).
Does anybody know a way around it ? 
I keep de-selecting all every time I check-in or worse – checking-in by mistake.

I am working with visual studio 2008

Answer (score 1):

I have the very same annoying problem. The several files checked out in my case are not due to debugging, but due to long term work.  Still, when I want to check-in, I'd like to do it for only few files of the list.  I don't think the answers above relate to the problem itself, but to the debug approach which is a side note for Gonen's issue.

Gonen, there's one thing you can do at least to avoid the mistakenly check-in, which is to prompt before checking in, and see if it's more then one file. You can configure that in the configuration screen above, just go to the sub-menu 'Visual Studio Team Foundation Server' and check the 'Prompt before check-in...'.

Answer (score 0):

Let us say that in your solution you have 5 projects. And one file is checked out in each project. Now if you were to go to pending changes window it will show you all files checked out across projects, solutions, branches. If you were interested in checking in the files that you have checked out only for Project 1. Then right click on project 1 and click 'Check-in'. You will see that although in the 'check-in window' all other checked out files will appear, only Project 1 checked out files will show up as checked.

**How about the Source Control Environment Options**
[image]

Wondering why the files are checked out during debugging, what options do u have checked in the Tfs=> Tools => Options => Source Control => Environment?

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not referring to several projects.
for example, in one case, I have several files that are checked out in order to enable debug features, that should not be checked in. but every time I checkin something, those files get checked in the pending changes, and I have to checked them off.

I have experience with several source controls (svn,cvs,perforce) and none had that problem.

Comment: Hey mate, why are the files checked out during debugging? What environment settings do u have in Tools => Options => Source Control => Environment?

Comment: None of course, none make any sense to me.
During debugging session, i change usually change some code, to help debug the problem, for example enable more logging then default ETC. I don't want to check-in those change.

Comment: Well if you modify the file it will be checked out and there is no work around from seeing those files pop up on the check in window. The only other thing i can think of is apply a check in policy to exclude files of certain type. This can be done through the power tools. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963